# Import raku's `dir` function into Perl

Tags: perl, raku

I've been learning perl6/raku for a while now, and I really like the `dir` routine https://docs.perl6.org/routine/dir.  It's very convenient and easy to use.

Is there any way that I could import/backport `dir` into Perl?  I am unable to get any results on internet searches.

Comment: Hi @con. You may wish to consider [IP6](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Perl6). I wrote an answer suggesting its use. But the install is currently failing for me on my local system so I've currently hidden (deleted) the answer. If and when I get confirmation it works I'll add the example of using Raku's `dir` in Perl 5 to my answer and undelete it, and write another comment here to make sure you're aware it works.

Comment: I've been too busy to chase this up yet but in the meantime, here's [a visible copy of my answer stored outside of stackoverflow](https://gist.github.com/raiph/4d54916f13f3094895f950d21b092bba).

Answer (score 8):

This is very similar to what you get from [readdir](https://perldoc.pl/functions/readdir).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $dh, $dirpath or die "Failed to open $dirpath: $!";
foreach my $file (readdir $dh) {
  next if $file eq '.' or $file eq '..';
  print "$dirpath/$file: $file\n";
}
```

My [Dir::ls](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dir::ls) makes this a little neater, but it's designed more to emulate `ls` than to be programmatically useful.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Dir::ls;
foreach my $file (ls $dirpath) {
  print "$dirpath/$file: $file\n";
}
```

[Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) makes the common case easy as usual - all paths are Path::Tiny objects.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny;
foreach my $filepath (path($dirpath)->children) {
  my $file = $filepath->basename;
  print "$filepath: $file\n";
}
```

And it can filter on a regex (applied to the basename, not the full path):

```
path($dirpath)->children(qr/\.txt$/);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is `File::List::Object` which has a `readdir` method that does something similar. It's not lazy though.

```
File::List::Object->new()->readdir('C:\');
```

Answer (score 1):

What [`dir`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/dir) does is three things

- Returns IO::Path handles
- ... filtered by a regex ..
- ... in a *lazy* list.

Path::Tiny mentioned by Grinnz would come closest... except it's not lazy. Laziness is not something that comes bundled with Perl. So you would have to combine it with something like [`Object::Trampoline`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Trampoline) to actually achieve that. You would have to "trampolinize" the construction of `Path::Tiny` objects using it.